# question about async/await node.js and function called again before it completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a function A() that gets called when a kafka event arrives.  This function has a bunch of await statements on async calls.  It doesn't really matter if it's kafka - it could be a webserver or some event that came from some other system.

I was explaining to a colleague that this function **can** be entered by another such event before the end of the method is reached.

To try prove it, I tried placing breakpoints all throughout the function, expecting for a given await to yield to another one of the promises that have been pushed off (to the event queue).  I expected to see a breakpoint get hit at the beginning of the function, before I reached one of the last ones in my function.

But that's not what I saw. I always saw the entire function get handled linearly - and only when I got past the last one, did I see another get hit at the beginning.

I know I must be correct, because if there's an await on a really long operation, then I should see the behavior I expect above.  Any idea what I could do to show this?  (or am I wrong in any of my reasoning here?)  Thanks!

Comment: Could you show a snippet of relevant code to make the question a bit more concrete? Is the "other" function async or sync? What do you mean by "the function can be entered", exactly? Thanks.

Comment: The only way this could happen with promises in general is that they are wrapped over something sync and blocking. Otherwise this is specific to how you handle a queue, or your debugging methods

Comment: I can't really show it more concretely. Imagine *any* function, riddled with awaits on asynch calls. This method is only called via web server requests let's say (so multi threaded source). I'm asking if this method could show a"context switch", due to an await on a long operation in one of those awaits, where another call stack gets the chance to do some work. I'd see that and prove it's possible via breakpoints, but I was unable to make that happen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function gets called again before a prior invocation has finished, it should be able to progress through both invocations in parallel, depending on when the different `await`s inside each resolve. For a mini-example:

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const fn = async (arg) => {
  console.log('point 1', arg);
  await delay(1000);
  console.log('point 2', arg);
  await delay(1000);
  console.log('point 3', arg);
  await delay(1000);
  console.log('point 4', arg);
  await delay(1000);
  return arg;
};

// main script:
fn('foo').then(arg => console.log(arg, 'done'));
setTimeout(() => {
  fn('bar').then(arg => console.log(arg, 'done'));
}, 500);
```

If your script does not have the same sort of behavior, something else is interfering - debug and double-check that you don't have a logic bug somewhere.

It could be that your asynchronous calls are not actually asynchronous, but are *blocking*:

```js
const delay = ms => {
  // JUST AN EXAMPLE of a heavy task
  // please never use this in real code
  const now = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - now < ms);
  return Promise.resolve();
};

const fn = async (arg) => {
  console.log('point 1', arg);
  await delay(200);
  console.log('point 2', arg);
  await delay(200);
  console.log('point 3', arg);
  await delay(200);
  console.log('point 4', arg);
  await delay(200);
  return arg;
};

// main script:
fn('foo').then(arg => console.log(arg, 'done'));
setTimeout(() => {
  fn('bar').then(arg => console.log(arg, 'done'));
}, 500);
```

In such a case, if you want to make the function truly capable of parallelism, have it do the heavy work in a child process instead of on the main thread.

Comment: This looks like the most promising answer. I can't wait to try this

Comment: Not near a computer right now, but if it's possible to see point 1, point 2, point 1, point 2, point 3, point 3..... Instead of 1 through 4 twice sequentially, this proves my point.

Comment: Even if you're on a phone, you should be able to press "Run code snippet" to see it working. (Don't use responsive mode)

Comment: Interesting - first few times I tried this - they both had foo, followed by bar, consistently.  I came back and tried again - and now the first one is interleaving as expected.  Weird!  Amazing answer, thank you so much for your help!  :-)  (cool feature too!!)

Answer (score 0):

When you're using async calls, if those have await, then the code would run linearly, since you are sending requests and waiting for them to finish. If you use `setTimeout(somefunction, 300)` that would run that `somefunction` in 300 milliseconds even though there's something else running, so you need to remove the await in order to have multiple calls in a real async way